# CMD set /a, modulus, and negative numbers

Tags: batch-file, cmd, modulo

Is CMD unable to evaluate the modulus of negative numbers using `set /a`?

`90 % 7` correctly equates to 6 in batch, however `-90 % 7` gives -6 instead of 1.

I thought that it might have been evaluating `-(90 % 7)`, but this doesn't seem to be the case as `(-90) % 7` also gives -6.

```
h:\uprof>set /a -90%7
-6
h:\uprof>set /a (-90)%7
-6
```

So - is this a limitation of CMDs set /a Modulus operator?

Comment: Why `-90 % 7` should give you 1 instead of -6?

Comment: According to the Google calculator - [(-90) Modulo 7 = 1](https://www.google.com.au/#q=-90%20%25%207).

Comment: Windows calculator also give us -6

Comment: Just to add into the confusion: [=1](http://www.miniwebtool.com/modulo-calculator/?number1=-90&number2=7), [=-6](http://www.dcode.fr/modulo-n-calculator), [=-6](https://www.easycalculation.com/algebra/modulo-calculator.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%` in CMD much like in other microsoft environments is a remainder function - not a true modulo operation. The remainder is accurate here to return -6 for your examples. Using `mod` in Excel is a true modulo which does return your expected 1.

Although it's written for C#, the article below has a great breakdown of the difference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you want true modulo, than you can use this:

```cmd
set a=-90
set b=7
set /a (a%b+b)%b
```

Answer (score 2):

As Jason W said, `%` isn't a modulo operator. But if you want *-b mod N*, maybe this can help:

```
@echo off
set /a num1=7
set /a num2=-90
:add
if %num2% LSS 0 set /a num2+=num1&goto add
echo/%num2%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found another expression which does not require calculating the modulus of negative numbers - at the expense of a few bytes (for [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

My solution with a loop - quite happy this turned out to work, as all other replies here didn't give me what I wanted. Just replace !VARIABEL1/2! with what you want to calculate. The !modulo! output is going to be the calculation. 
E.g.:
mod_a: 10,
mod_b: 4,
modulo: 2

Maybe it's not the most elegant way, but it's batch after all. :D

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set mod_a=!VARIABLE1!
set mod_b=!VARIABLE2!
set mod_counter=0
for /l %%k in (1,1,!mod_a!) do (
    set /a mod_counter+=1
    set /a mod_a-=1
    if !mod_counter!==!mod_b! set /a mod_counter=0
    if !mod_a!==0 set modulo=!mod_counter!
)
if not defined modulo set modulo=0
echo modulo is !modulo!
```

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Here a batch file that calculates from -10 up to and including +10. The modulo of these numbers, 7. The first part does the looping' the second part, `:MOD`, is the subroutine that actually does the calculation.

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (-10,1,10) do call :MOD %%i 7
pause
GOTO :END

:MOD
  set a=%1
  set b=%2
  set /a c=%a% %% %b% + %b%
  set /a c=c %% %b%
  echo.%1 modulo %2: %c%
  goto :END

:END
```